# SQL - Insert a row into table only if not exists and count is less than a threshold

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Other similar questions deal these two problems separately, but I want to merge them in a single statement. I'm using Python3 with psycopg2 library on a PostgreSQL database.

I have a table with 3 fields: ID, name, bool (BIT)

I want to insert a row in this table only if does not exists an other row with same 'name' and 'bool' = 0 and the total count of rows with same `ID` is less than a given threshold.
More specific my table should contain at most a given threshold number of rows with same `ID`. Those rows can have the same 'name', but only one of those rows with same `ID` and same 'name' can have 'bool'= 0.

I tried with this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
      SELECT 12345, abcdf , 0 FROM table 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM table 
                WHERE ID = 12345 AND name = abcdf AND bool = 0) 
                    HAVING (SELECT count(*) FROM table 
                        WHERE ID = 12345) < threshold 
                    RETURNING ID;
```

but the row is inserted anyway.
Then I tried the same statement replacing 'HAVING' with 'AND', but it insert all the threshold rows together.

Comment: I would try the individual queries on their own(w/o ```INSERT``` part), so the query in the ```NOT EXISTS``` and in the ```HAVING```. See if they return what you expect. Then combine them(again as just straight ```SELECT```) to see what is returned.

Comment: I tried, in fact my solution is actually composed by 2 queries: the first get a the  `COUNT` of the `SELECT` inside `NOT EXISTS` and if it is 0 I execute the `INSERT` with `HAVING` clause.